# manual variable increment

Tags: xml, jasper-reports

I can't find the way to just create a variable and modify it during report generation.

I have declared an integer variable:

```
<variable name="my_counter" class="java.lang.Integer" calculation="System">
    <initialValueExpression><![CDATA[new Integer(0)]]></initialValueExpression>
</variable>
```

That seems to work, and I can print its value without problems. But I want to increment that value during report generation: when the XML (the datasource for the report) contains certain parameters I want to increase the value (my_counter++).

**What I want to achieve**, in pseudocode:

```
<textField printWhenExpression="$P{BANANAS}!=null"> ($V{my_counter}++)+" The XML contains <bananas>" </textField>
<textField printWhenExpression="$P{APPLES}!=null"> ($V{my_counter}++)+" The XML contains <apples>" </textField>
<textField printWhenExpression="$P{GRAPES}!=null"> ($V{my_counter}++)+" The XML contains <grapes>" </textField>
<textField printWhenExpression="$P{ORANGES}!=null"> ($V{my_counter}++)+" The XML contains <oranges>" </textField>
```

**The expected result** for an XML file containing bananas, apples and oranges would be:

```
1. The XML contains <bananas>
2. The XML contains <apples>
3. The XML contains <oranges>
```

I've tried that, but **the current result** looks more like this:

```
0. The XML contains <bananas>
0. The XML contains <apples>
0. The XML contains <oranges>
```

So it seems that the variable `my_counter` is not being modified. Why? How can I modify its value for each displayed textField?

Comment: It is better to talk in terminology *the row contains <bananas>*. You have fields (from *XML* datasource, for example) and you can use this fields in variable's expression

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to use a mutable value holder instead of `java.lang.Integer` for the variable.  `java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger` would do for instance (you don't need atomicity, you can also go with MutableInt from Commons Lang).

Once you declare your variable as AtomicInteger, you can do `$V{my_counter}.getAndIncrement()` in your expressions.

Comment: It works! I've just had a little problem with the initial value expression, you must use the full class path: ``new java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger(1)`` instead of just ``new AtomicInteger(1)``. Thank you @dada67

Comment: The only reason I suggested AtomicInteger is that it's a readily available mutable int class.  As noted in my reply, atomicity/thread safety is not actually required, you could go with other mutable int class if you have one at hand (you'll also need a method that increments and returns the value as you can't use void methods in report expressions).