# How to increment a variable everytime I use it?

Tags: jasper-reports

How to increment a variable everytime I use it?

I made a variable called `variable_1` and it starts at 1 and should increment every time I call/use it.

[image: Variable properties]

Comment: Yes but deleted it and want to ask it differently

Comment: There is no such setting in the variable dialog, you are probably having a [x-y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/320339)

Comment: Probably you could do it with a report scriplet and a Incrementer Factory class, but again I think you should re-think what you actually need, there probably is a simpler solution.

Comment: Okay but there must be a simpler solution?  I just want it to increment from the beginning until the end where I use it

Comment: `there must be a simpler solution?` - Using Java Map or using scriptlet

Comment: Declare the variable as java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger (you probably don't need atomicity, but it's convenient), use new java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger(1) as initial expression and then do $V{Variable_1}.getAndIncrement() in all the places where you use it.  You also need to set Calculation to System so that the initial value is preserved throughout the report.

Comment: Thank you it works and a way much simpler solution

Comment: Possible duplicate of [manual variable increment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17144186/manual-variable-increment)

Comment: Thank you @AlexK, I forgot I had answered the same question before.

Comment: @dada67 I remembered your great solution after some pause :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thank you @dada67

[image]

I made the changes to my report and it worked.

`new java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger(1)` is my  Initial Value Expression.

Thanks again