# In a JasperReport, is there a way to formulate a 'Print When Expression' for the last page of a group?

Tags: jasper-reports

Here's the scenario:

- I'm creating a report to generate statements for multiple customers, grouping by customer.
- The statement will have at least three pages of information, possible more, depending on the number of individual line items in a sub-report in detail 1 section.
- When printed, the statement will be duplexed
- If the customer has an odd number of pages of information, the back side of the last page will have a statement like, 'This page intentionally left blank'.
- I have detail sections 2, 3, and 4, starting with a page break.
- The Detail 4 page has the 'intentially left blank' note. I am able to create a Print When Expression to suppress the page if it's an odd-numbered page.

However, I have a watermark/background image, and page n of nn in a page header that I would like to suppress on that 'blank' page.

I there a way to know that either that Detail-4 section is being printed? Or a way to know it is on the final page for the group? The later seems somewhat feasible, except the page number has an Evaluation Time of 'Now' and the 'of nn' has an Evaluation Time of group, so it seems logical that I should be able to say something like 'If current page number equals the total number of page in the group...', then suppress the objects from printing.

Can either of those scenarios be accomplished? Or are there other options?

The only think I could think of to try was to create a variable that would increment each time a band was processed, and reset by group - thinking I could try to determine when the value was 4 and use that in my Print When expression.

I tried placing the variable as a text field in each band, and changing the Evaluation Time to 'band' (or 'Now'), but that didn't seem to do anything. It never incremented. For the variable itself, there is no Evaluation Time of 'band' available.

Answer (score 0):

For anybody curious of the same, I found an answer from dada67 in the post [How to increment a variable every time I use it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44044582/how-to-increment-a-variable-everytime-i-use-it)

I created a variable called 'bandCount' - though in my case, I had a 'Reset Type' at my group level; and subsequently placed a hidden text field in each band, with an Expression of $V{bandCount}.getAndIncrement() as noted in the post. For the elements I wanted to see on all pages except the final Detail-4 section, I added a 'Print When Expression' of '$V{bandCount}.intValue() < 4'.