# How to call subdataset's query only once and use it in detail band in JasperReports?

Tags: jasper-reports

Is it possible to create a subdataset and call it's query only once while using it to fill a table that is located in details band? 
I don't want to call the database again for each row in main dataset, instead I want to filter the table with main dataset's field. I have managed to filter it, but in my db logs, I noticed that the query was executed for each row in main dataset. I am using JasperSoft studio 6.3.

Comment: It is better to move component with subdataset  to another band (Title)

Comment: The component with subdataset needs to be filtered by main dataset's field, so it has to be in detail band.

Comment: Did you try to use *printWhen* expression? You can use *printWhen* in pair with [manual variable increment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17144186/876298) (if you condition depends on counter only)

Comment: I am not sure how printWhen might help me. My problem is not in filtering the table, but instead, my problem is that the database query from the subdataset is being called for each row. My 2 datasets are quite different, they only have one column in common, and that is the column i am filtering the table with. I want the query being executed only once...

Comment: If the element (table) with subquery is hidden (removed) is subquery really fired? Did you check it?

Comment: I need the table visible for each row :). It just has to be filtered.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147685/discussion-between-bozo-tegeltija-and-alex-k).

Comment: You can always place 2 tables: the 1st one (with subquery) is shown for first row, 2nd hidden (without subquery) and vice versa: 2nd is shown for others rows and 1st one is hidden